# Orkut/Flickr Framework for Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am aware of Google+, Facebook and Twitter framework in iPhone. But for my new app requirement is that user should be able to post via FB/Twitter/G+/Orkut/Flickr.

Is there any such **framework for Orkut/Flickr** as opposed to FB/Twitter/G+ Or, do i need to redirect user to Orkut/Flickr and placing it in UIWebView as an traditional practice in webview.

Thanks for any help in advance :).

Comment: May i know as why is it downvoted??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you even search for this on google:

Flickr: http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157616815681140/
Direct link to the library: https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr

Orkut API: https://developers.google.com/orkut/